# Scroll to div with some px in less

Tags: jquery

I find here in Stack Overflow a simple script written in jQuery which allows to have a smooth scroll to a specific div id, clicking a button:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

Everything works perfectly, but I have a little problem: in the site I have a fixed menu, that clutters this script. When I click the button for scroll to a specific div, the menu takes a part of the div that I want to see (overwrap the div), so the div is not visible to 100%.

I want to ask if there is a manner to scroll to a specific div removing some px, equivalent to the height in px of the menu.

Example:

Page:

[image]

I click the button, and I get this effect:

[image]

But I want this effect:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the height of the menu bar and subtract it from the offset like for example if the menu is 60px

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top-60
}, 2000);
});
```